# How to connect to SQL using Pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, macos, pyodbc, apple-silicon

I want to connect to a SQL server using Pyodbc, but it always display the same error.

This is my code so far:

```
import pyodbc
try:
 conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER = {SQL Server};SERVER=master;DATABASE=Clinica;UID=djimenez;PWD=PRIVATE')
 print ("Conexion succesful")
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
```

and the displaying error is:

```
('IM002', '[IM002] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I'm still a novice in this kind of stuff, So i don't know what that means. I used the terminal and looked

```
where unixODBC
```

and it said that it was not found. I tried to install it but it said it was already installed. I search up my problem and i came across to MarkLogic. I tried to download that but apparently, it isn't compatible to Mac M1, that's where i am. SO im stuck and don't know what to do.. Any help please?

Comment: You need to specify the name of the server where your SQL Server is running.  You have `SERVER=master`.  Is that actually the name of the machine?

Comment: So is `SQL Server` actually a driver you have installed? For support of Apple M1 processors you'd typically install [ODBC Driver 17.8 for SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos) or later and reference it in the connection string as `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};` or `DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};`, depending upon which version you actually installed.

Comment: If you install ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server make sure you read about and understand the breaking changes in [ODBC Driver 18.0 for SQL Server Released](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/odbc-driver-18-0-for-sql-server-released/ba-p/3169228)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get get Python to interact with SQL Server.

```
# connect to SQL Server
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

driver= '{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}'

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={SQL Server};'
    r'SERVER=LAPTOP-CEDUMII6;'
    r'DATABASE=TestDB;'
    r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
)
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM Employee')

# print contents of table
for row in cursor:
    print('row = %r' % (row,))
```

Relevant resources:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-SQL-Server-from-Windows

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2015/03/11/python-and-data-sql-server-as-a-data-source-for-python-applications.aspx

Or......

```
# push dataframe to table in SQL Server
engine = create_engine(cnxn, fast_executemany=True)
df_append.to_sql('your_table', engine, index=False, if_exists='append')
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that you are lacking the driver. In a nutshell, That connection string is used to establish the connection to your desired server. In the first part of the string, You are directing the connection to where the driver lives. You are missing the driver or when you downloaded it you only downloaded the driver itself and you will have to update the "driver config file" for lack for a better term. Any ODBC connection will leverage this file to get the location of the driver. For my mac it is located at `/usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini` and if you were going to connect to a Microsoft SQL server your connection string would start off like `DRIVER = {ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}....`. This means in the `odbcinst.ini` you will see this entry

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server] --> This matches name in the connection string
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

Now in your case when you go to the file you will not see `{SQL Server}` to fix this go in to your file and manually add a configuration and make sure you are pointing to the where the driver is. Then your error will be resolved for at least that portion.